# Unable to patch 2 errata on OpenBSD 5.5

Tags: openbsd, patch

I'm trying to patch OpenBSD 5.5 with all of the 10 errata.

The command I use to patch is:

```
signify -Vep /etc/signify/openbsd-55-base.pub -x /path/to/patch/ \
-m - | (cd /usr/src && patch -p0)
```

007_sendmail.patch.sig and 009_dhcp.patch.sig present some problems when patching.

The error message when applying 007_sendmail.patch.sig is:

```
Patching file gnu/usr.sbin/sendmail/conf.c using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 5309
done
#cd gnu/usr.sbin/sendmail
ksh:cd: /root/gnu/usr.sbin/sendmail - No such file or directory
#make obj
make: don't know how to make obj
Stop in /root
```

009_dhcp.patch.sig also presents some issues:

```
#cd sbin/dhclient
ksh:cd: /root/sbin/dhclient - No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you sure `-x /path/to/patch/` is what you really mean?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty clear here:

```
#cd gnu/usr.sbin/sendmail
ksh:cd: /root/gnu/usr.sbin/sendmail - No such file or directory
```

You are in /root, and you should be in /usr/src